# Get the user-agent from tcpdump

Tags: openwrt, tcpdump, mail-user-agent

I'm working on a monitoring application for my home gateway and I want to know the device type of all connected clients. For that purpose I'm using `tcpdump` to extract the user-agent of all devices

```
tcpdump -vvAls0 | grep 'User-Agent:'
```

[image]

but I can't figure out each client user-agent.
is there a way to distinct the correspondent user-agent for each device.

Answer (score 1):

The useragent alone won't be enough to distinct two different devices running the same browser, not mentioning the ability for the user to alter useragent.

Moreover, basing detection only on useragent makes all non HTTP clients invisible to your monitoring application.